# Python-LDAP integration

Tags: python, ldap, authkit

I need to integrate Python with LDAP. I just need to choose the best way to make Python talk to LDAP. I understand there are many ways to do this, including using a prebuilt toolkit such as the AuthKit or writing a thing ourselves with LDAP modules and functions. What do you recommend?

Comment: I'd question the decision to close this question on two grounds:

Comment: 1. I find the answers constructive, giving real-world examples. 2) Personally I find any detailed discussion of using python (directly without calling C++) for integrating enterprise systems very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used the python-ldap library to communicate with LDAP servers and Windows Active Directory.  You can download it from pypi here http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ldap/2.3.10

Answer (score 0):

The package pointed to by Mr. janglin is very effective
A good series of articles by Matt Butcher, link to first one http://www.packtpub.com/article/installing-and-configuring-the-python-ldap-library-and-binding-to-an-ldap-directory

python-ldap site is http://www.python-ldap.org/  It has links to code, documentation and examples.

Cheerio

Aalok